# Fixed Table Header with Sorting

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

Alright, so I've got the [scroller](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-scroller.html) widget for [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) working, but it's messing up the header sizing of my table.  At first, I thought it was some extra code used for [complex sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26661661/complex-table-sorting) that was causing the problem, but I've removed all the extra code and am still have trouble.

Then I thought, maybe my styling, so I cleared all that out can replaced it with only a border to the make the issue visible.

```
td, th {
 border: 1px #000 solid;
}

.th-inner {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 line-height: 28px; /* height of header */
}
```

When that still didn't reveal the problem, I started to shorten the execution of `tablesorter()` until there was absolutely nothing but it calling the widget.

Here's the JSFiddle with my CSS but none of the extra code for the complex sorting: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv19a465/

Here's the JSFiddle with the border-only CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv19a465/2/

All indications are that there is a margin setting messing it up, but I can't find anything in console, nor does setting it to 0 for everything seem to affect it.

```
table, tr, td, th {
 padding: 0 !important;
 margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: the cause of the offset is the spacing in between each cell's border...to eliminate this you could just add `table, tr, td, th { border-collapse: collapse}` to your styles

Comment: @almightyBoognish: `border-collapse` did help, but it didn't quite fix the issue.  With exception to the due date (which is equal) and public notes (which is 3px larger), all the `th` are 2px smaller than the `td`.  Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv19a465/3/

Comment: I don't have enough information on how these `<th />` widths are calculated/defined so I can't help you but it looks like border-widths need to be taken into consideration when determining the width of the table headers

Comment: @almightyBoognish: Thanks for trying.  The code is linked at http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/widgets/widget-scroller.js, and it appears to set it dynamically using the widths of the content before it is duplicated, but I'm not an expert at jQuery, hence all the trouble I have with it. ^^'

Answer (score 0):

You need to add addition params to your `tablesorter`config to have it correctly displayed.

```
$(function(){
 $('#mainlist').tablesorter({
     widgets: [ 'scroller' ],
     headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}'
     widthFixed : true,
 });
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Lv19a465/5/

Comment: Actually, yours isn't working, either.  You have the comma at the end of the `widthFixed` instead of `headerTemplate`.  The script errors and doesn't execute.  If you position the comma properly, you'll find the issue is still there, but thank you for trying. ^^

Comment: My bad, I overlooked this.

Comment: No worries.  Thanks for looking. ^^